# how to add JDK to classpath (mac)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, classpath

Ive been using Eclipse, and this hasnt been an issue, but Im trying out IntelliJIDE.  In order to do so, I need to install JDK and load it in my classpath.

Ive never accessed my classpath before, and Im reading conflicting reports on here about whether I need to add JDK to my classpath or if I should simply pass it to Java via commandline while running program.

I really know nothing about said classpath and am not even sure how to access mine.  I dont want to mess with it and re-route all of my java libs.

Comment: A couple of things... 1st, you don't need to add the jdk to your classpath. 2nd, if you're programming in java you probably should at least google 'classpath' and read a couple of short articles before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it in .bash_profile file like

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=$PATH:${JAVA_HOME}/bin
```

The .bash_profile file should in /User/"your username" if it is not there please create it.